# How to join three table rest api .net core 5?

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest

I have three entities.

First x second y third z

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<y> y{ get; set; }
    public virtual z z{ get; set; }

          For Y

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int xID{ get; set; }
    public x x { get; set; }

   FOR Z

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int xId { get; set; }
    public x x { get; set; }
```

When i try to return await _context.x.ToListAsync(); y and z column null. Why is that? How to connect each other?

I used fluent api for relationship.

Actually i need this query. How to write async?

Select table1.ID ,table1.Name
from Table1 inner join Table2 on Table1 .ID =Table2 .ID
inner join Table3 on table2.ID=Table3 .ID

Comment: Table3 has no use in that query, why are you joining with it?

Comment: Actually i used normally query Select table1.ID ,table1.Name from Table1 inner join Table2 on Table1 .ID =Table2 .ID
inner join Table3 on table1.ID=Table3 .ID
but i just need how to connect like this if i used .Join( context.Table1) its a numerrical error 

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string Name, string x>>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<.Entities.x>>'

Comment: You keep asking a new problem each time. Please focus on one thing at a time.

Comment: I have a just one problem. I have 3 tables related each other one to one one to many and i want to write rest api.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some `Include()` calls.

Your query should be

```
 await _context.x.Include(e => e.y).Include(e => e.z).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: When i try include 

System.InvalidOperationException: The expression 'y.Name' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

Comment: Actually i need this query :

Select table1.ID ,table1.Name 
from Table1 inner join Table2 on Table1 .ID =Table2 .ID  
inner join Table3 on table2.ID=Table3 .ID 

How can i write async?